# onActivityResult is not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-intent, start-activity

I have an activity 1 which send intent to activity 2 as bellow:

**activity 1**

```
periodDatetv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.this, SettingsPeriodDate.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });
```

**activity 2**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        todayCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        pickedDateCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SettingsPeriodDate.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.perioddatesettings);

        datePicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.DataPickerDate);

        dialog.show();

        Button okDialogButton = (Button) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        okDialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
                int currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                Day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                Month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
                Year = datePicker.getYear();

                todayCalendar.set(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);
                pickedDateCalendar.set(Year, Month, Day);

                System.err.println("Choseon date = " + Day + "/" + Month + "/"
                        + Year);
                System.err.println("Today date = " + currentDay + "/"
                        + currentMonth + "/" + currentYear);

                int Days = daysBetween(todayCalendar.getTime(),
                        pickedDateCalendar.getTime());

                System.err.println("Daaaaays === " + Days);

                if (pickedDateCalendar.after(todayCalendar) || Days >= 1) {
                    System.err.println("Inside if pop it");
                    PopIt("Error ", "Please check the date again");

                }

                else {

                    periodDateSharedPreferences(Year, Month, Day);

                }
                dialog.dismiss();
                System.err.println("befor back");
                Intent saved2 = new Intent(SettingsPeriodDate.this,
                        Settings.class);
                startActivityForResult(saved2, 100);


            }

        });

        Button cancelDialogButton = (Button) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonCancel);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        cancelDialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(SettingsPeriodDate.this,Settings.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    public int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
        return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }

    public void periodDateSharedPreferences(int calculatedPeriodYear,
            int calculatedPeriodMonth, int calculatedPeriodDay) {
        SharedPreferences periodDatePreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = periodDatePreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("periodChosenDay", calculatedPeriodDay);
        editor.putInt("periodChosenMonth", calculatedPeriodMonth);
        editor.putInt("periodChosenYear", calculatedPeriodYear);
        editor.commit();

        System.err.println("periodChosenDay preferences"
                + periodDatePreferences.getInt("periodChosenDay", 0));
        System.err.println("periodChosenMonth preferences"
                + periodDatePreferences.getInt("periodChosenMonth", 0));
        System.err.println("periodChosenYear preferences"
                + periodDatePreferences.getInt("periodChosenYear", 0));
        Toast.makeText(SettingsPeriodDate.this, "The date was saved",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        finish();
    }

    public void PopIt(String title, String message) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("Please check again");
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        final AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();

        dlg.show();

        final Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                dlg.dismiss();
                t.cancel();
            }
        }, 100000);
    }
```

and I get the result in ***activity 1*** as bellow :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case 100:
            System.err.println("after intent back 111111=== ");

             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            System.err.println("after intent back if=== ");

            int day = data.getIntExtra("Day", 0);
            int month = data.getIntExtra("Month", 0);
            int year = data.getIntExtra("Year", 0);
            System.err.println("after intent back =///== " + day + "-" + month
                    + "-" + year);
            Toast.makeText(Settings.this,day+"?"+month+"?"+year,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            periodDatetv.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
            break;

         }

        }
    }
```

But it never runs the onActivityResult method ! what is the wrong in my code ? please tell me .. and thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you setting the return value?  I can't see it.

Comment: startActivityForResult(i, 0);

Comment: Do you have this problem on all devices?

Comment: I am testing it on Emulator

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper now that you're calling `setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)` in `onCreate()`, your `onActivityResult()` will be called, but `resultCode` will always be `RESULT_CANCELED`, because you do not set result before you call `finish()` (I mean setting result with code ` RESULT_OK` - `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)`)

Comment: why you are calling setResult(RESULT_CANCELED); in activity2 onCreate.

Comment: I edited it again please check

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper I updated my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14353895/779408

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper when you have to receive on activity result, is for ok button click on cancel button click?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper check out my answer. It should be clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setResult(RESULT_OK);` before `finish()` method from second activity

from the second activity which you want should return some result to first activity

Comment: is this you code to return from first activity to second activity?
Intent saved2 = new Intent(SettingsPeriodDate.this,
                        Settings.class);
                startActivityForResult(saved2, 100);

Comment: just use setResult(RESULT_OK); and there after finish(); method your code will run as charm instead of that code

Comment: setResult() return to the place where the intent was sent ?

Comment: yes actually when you do startActivityForResult(INTENT, REQUEST_CODE); from activity A it waits for the result to catch in onActivityResult method in A and in B when you work is over and you want to return back a result to A just use setResult(RESULT_OK); if you work is done properly else use setResult(CANCLED); if your work is not done in B. this indicates A that I am getting result from B or not and it will catch in onActivityResult method

Comment: Ok but I want to use the data that was saved in shared prefernces in activity 2, I want to use them in activity 1 because of that I used on activity result, how can I use them now ?

Comment: Just put them into intent.putExtra(key, value)(String data, int data or anyting) and pass it as setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); and in activity A access that data from the Intent data parameter of onActivityResult method

Answer (score 2):

You commented out your `setResult()` call in activity 2.

In case you are starting your activity with `startActivityForResult()`, the activity you start (activity 2 in your case) needs to call `setResult()` each time it is about to be finished.

See this example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blablabla)

    //we do this here to make sure result is set even if user leaves
    //activity, for example, by pressing back/home buttons
    //result we set here will be overridden by any latter calls if they occur
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);         

    //do some processing here
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    //now let's send the result back
    intent.putExtra(result);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}

private void another_method() {
    //do some processing here too
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    //sending the result back
    intent.putExtra(result);
    //need to call setResult() here too
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I'm scanning the code and I still can't see setResult, even commented out! :)

Comment: at first it was commented out, and then after one of the edits it just disappeared :)

Comment: Ok but I want to use the data that was saved in shared prefernces in activity 2, I want to use them in activity 1 because of that I used on activity result, how can I use them now ?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper put any data you want as extra to the intent you set as result, and then get it from extras in `onActivityResult()`, don't forget that you need to use the same key

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you start `SettingsPeriodDate` from `Settings` and then `Settings` from `SettingsPeriodDate`.

You should not be starting Settings again. Just `setResult()` and `finish()` when your work with `SettingsPeriodDate` is done

Comment: Does setResult() activate onActivityResult() ?

Comment: that's not the issue. setResult is not mandatory, it will just give you data that you fetch using `data.getIntExtras` for instance. The important part is that you start Settings when you should not

Answer (score 0):

before finish activity to call `setResult(RESULT_OK)`. I can't find it in your code. Instead of setting result you are call the activity one again. So it will create new activity. Don't call new activity with activity 1 intent.

Comment: request code and result code are different, 0 and 1  are reserved for result, not for request

Comment: yes you are right. But in most of code we will use 0 and 1, if you use  big number then can identify request code easily.

Comment: For the sake of identification I would store request code as static constant somewhere and use its name.

Comment: wrong wrong wrong. request code is not result code. you can use any value you want as a request code.